# How to check what is included in NPM package

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, mediapipe

I installed this package: npm install @mediapipe/camera_utils

I would like to know how to find the contents of a package.

Comment: https://bundlephobia.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good trick I've found is to use the website [npmfs.com](https://npmfs.com) instead of [npmjs.com](https://npmjs.com) (just replace "s" with "f" in a package url).

[Here're the contents of that particular package](https://npmfs.com/package/@mediapipe/camera_utils/) (per each version)
and here're the [contents](https://npmfs.com/package/@mediapipe/camera_utils/0.1.1617146909/camera_utils.js) of `camera_utils.js` from the latest version:

```js
(function(){/*
 Copyright The Closure Library Authors.
 SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
*/
'use strict';var e="function"==typeof Object.defineProperties?Object.defineProperty:function(a,b,c){if(a==Array.prototype||a==Object.prototype)return a;a[b]=c.value;return a};function f(a){a=["object"==typeof globalThis&&globalThis,a,"object"==typeof window&&window,"object"==typeof self&&self,"object"==typeof global&&global];for(var b=0;b<a.length;++b){var c=a[b];if(c&&c.Math==Math)return c}throw Error("Cannot find global object");}var h=f(this);
function k(a,b){if(b)a:{var c=h;a=a.split(".");for(var d=0;d<a.length-1;d++){var g=a[d];if(!(g in c))break a;c=c[g]}a=a[a.length-1];d=c[a];b=b(d);b!=d&&null!=b&&e(c,a,{configurable:!0,writable:!0,value:b})}}var l="function"==typeof Object.assign?Object.assign:function(a,b){for(var c=1;c<arguments.length;c++){var d=arguments[c];if(d)for(var g in d)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(d,g)&&(a[g]=d[g])}return a};k("Object.assign",function(a){return a||l});var m=this||self;var n={facingMode:"user",width:640,height:480};function p(a,b){this.video=a;this.h=0;this.g=Object.assign(Object.assign({},n),b)}function q(a){window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){r(a)})}function t(a,b){a.video.srcObject=b;a.video.onloadedmetadata=function(){a.video.play();q(a)}}function r(a){var b=null;a.video.paused||a.video.currentTime===a.h||(a.h=a.video.currentTime,b=a.g.onFrame());b?b.then(function(){q(a)}):q(a)}
p.prototype.start=function(){var a=this;navigator.mediaDevices&&navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia||alert("No navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia exists.");var b=this.g;return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:{facingMode:b.facingMode,width:b.width,height:b.height}}).then(function(c){t(a,c)}).catch(function(c){console.error("Failed to acquire camera feed: "+c);alert("Failed to acquire camera feed: "+c);throw c;})};var u=["Camera"],v=m;
u[0]in v||"undefined"==typeof v.execScript||v.execScript("var "+u[0]);for(var w;u.length&&(w=u.shift());)u.length||void 0===p?v[w]&&v[w]!==Object.prototype[w]?v=v[w]:v=v[w]={}:v[w]=p;}).call(this);
```

Note: NPM is actually adding this feature natively through the Explore tab but it's currently in beta.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

- First of all the best way to check will be [npm
  website](https://www.npmjs.com/)  itself from where you are
  downloading this plugin.
- During the installation itself you can check by command `npm install -ddd`
- If you are willing to know more what all package content you need to
  go to `node_modules` folder, find the package name which you are
  looking for.  Inside that folder you can find its own
  `pacakge.json` file which includes all of its dependencies.